# Raku list addition operator `Z+` 'fails' unless one of the lists is forced

Tags: arrays, list, raku, rakudo

I'm struggling to understand why the zip-add `Z+` operator does not work on some cases.

I have some 2-element lists that I'd like to sum.

These work as expected whether I use lists or arrays:

```
say (1, 2) Z+ (3, 4) # (4, 6)
say [1, 2] Z+ (3, 4) # (4, 6)
say [1, 2] Z+ [3, 4] # (4, 6)
say (1, 2) Z+ [3, 4] # (4, 6)
```

Now we will do the same thing but I'll change the right operand with a value stored elsewhere. In this case I have an array of lists:

```
my @foo = (1,1), (2,2);
say @foo.WHAT;              # (Array)
say @foo[1].WHAT;           # (List)
say @foo[1];                # (2,2)
say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1];       # (5)  ???
```

Which gives the unexpected (at least for me :)) result of `(5)`.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.

First one is to force the got element to be a list:

```
my @foo = (1,1), (2,2);
say @foo.WHAT;              # (Array)
say @foo[1].WHAT;           # (List)   <== It was already a list, but...
say @foo[1];                # (2,2)
say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1].list;  # <== changed. (5,5)
```

And the other one is change the `@foo` definition to be a list instead of an array (either by `is List` or by binding `:=` the value)

```
my @foo is List = (1,1), (2,2);   # <=== Changed
say @foo.WHAT;              # (Array)
say @foo[1].WHAT;           # (List)   <== It was already a list
say @foo[1];                # (2,2)
say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1];       # (5,5)
```

Why the first case didn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way of looking at things...

```
my @foo = (1,1), (2,2);
say @foo.WHAT;              # (Array)
say @foo[1].WHAT;           # (List)   <== It was already a list, right?
```

**==> No, it wasn't.**

This is the primary key to your question in two respects:

- First, as Liz notes, when trying to understand what's going on when you encounter a surprise, use `dd`, not `say`, because `dd` focuses on the underlying reality.
- Second, it's important to understand the role of [`Scalar`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Scalar)s in Raku, and how that sharply distinguishes `Array`s from `List`s.

---

Another way to see the underlying reality, and the role of `Scalar`s, is to expand your examples a little:

```
my @foo = (1,1), (2,2);
say @foo.WHAT;              # (Array)  <== Top level elements "autovivify" as `Scalar`s
say @foo[1].VAR.WHAT;       # (Scalar) <== The element was a `Scalar`, not a `List`
say @foo[1].WHAT;           # (List)   <== The `Scalar` returns the value it contains
@foo[1] = 42;               # Works.   <== The `Scalar` supports mutability

my @foo2 is List = (1,1), (2,2);
say @foo2.WHAT;              # (List)  <== `List` elements *don't* "autovivify"
say @foo2[1].VAR.WHAT;       # (List)  <== `VAR` on a non-`Scalar` is a no op
say @foo2[1].WHAT;           # (List)  <== This time `@foo2[1]` IS a *`List`*
@foo2[1] = ...;              # Attempt to assign to `List` bound to `@foo2[1]` fails
@foo2[1] := ...;             # Attempt to bind to `@foo2[1]` element fails
```

I'll draw attention to several aspects of the above:

- *A `Scalar` generally keeps quiet about itself*

  A `Scalar` returns the value it contains in an [r-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#Assignment:_l-values_and_r-values) context, unless you explicitly seek it out with `.VAR`.
- *`Scalar` containers can be read/write or readonly*

  Until I wrote this answer, I had not cleanly integrated this aspect into my understanding of Raku's use of `Scalar`s. Perhaps it's obvious to others but I feel it's worth mentioning here because the `Scalar` indicated by the `$(...)` display from `dd` and `.raku` is a readonly one -- you can't assign to it.
- *An `Array` "autovivifies" (automatically creates and binds) a read/write `Scalar` for each of its elements*

  If a value is *assigned* to an indexed position (say `@foo[42]`) of a (non-native) `Array`, then if that element does *not* currently `:exist` (ie `@foo[42]:exists` is `False`), then a fresh read/write `Scalar` is "autovivified" as the first step in processing the assignment.
- *A `List` *never* autovivifies a `Scalar` for any of its elements*

  When a value is "assigned" (actually bound, even if the word "assigned" is used) to an indexed position in a *`List`*, no autovivification ever occurs. A `List` *can* include `Scalar`s, including read/write ones, but the only way that can happen is if an *existing* read/write `Scalar` is "assigned" to an element (indexed position), eg `my @foo := (42, $ = 99); @foo[1] = 100; say @foo; # (42 100)`.

---

And now we can understand your code that yields `(5)`:

```
my @foo = (1,1), (2,2);     # `@foo` is bound to a fresh non-native `Array`
say @foo[1].VAR.WHAT;       # (Scalar) -- @foo[1] is an autovivified `Scalar`
say @foo[1];                # (2,2) -- `say` shows value contained by `Scalar`

say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1];       # (5) --- because it's same as follows:

say +$(2,2);                # 2 -- number of elements in a two element list †
say (3,3) Z+ 2;             # (5) -- `Z` stops if either side exhausted
```

<sup>**†**</sup> We're applying a coercive numeric operation (`+`) to a list (`Positional` value), not to its elements. A list, coerced to a number, is its "length" (count of elements). (Certainly for a non-sparse one. I'm not sure about sparse ones.)

Comment: Thanks! Further reading for my future me: https://docs.raku.org/language/containers

Answer (score 10):

If you remove the `+` from the `Z`, and you use `dd` instead of `say`, it may become clearer:

```
dd (3,3) Z @foo[1];  # ((3, $(2, 2)),).Seq
```

So in this case, you get a list with `3` and `(2,2)`.  Note the `$` before the `(2,2)`: that means it's itemized: to be considered a single item.

Now with `Z+`, instead of creating a list, you're going to *add* the values.

When you write:

```
say 3 + (42,666);    # 5
```

you get `5` because you're adding *the number of elements in the list* to `3`.  That's why you're winding up with `5` in your example as well, **not** because the values in the list are `2`.

In the other cases the `Z` operators sees non-itemized lists and so *will* iterate over its elements as you expected.

In case of doubt, make sure that you use `dd` instead of `say` in debugging: it will give you the nitty gritty of an expression, and not just a "gist" :-)

Comment: Thanks! Why `((1,1),)[0]` returns a non-itemized list, but on the other hand, `[(1,1),][0]` returns an itemized one?

Comment: @julio `[ , , ]` creates an array, which itemized its elements. `( , , )` creates a list, which is not itemized by default

Answer (score 1):

Starting from:

```
my @foo = (1,1), (2,2);
```

Do:

```
say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1][*];   # (5 5)
```

OR

```
say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1][];    # (5 5)
```

OR

```
say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1]<>;    # (5 5)
```

OR

```
say (3,3) Z+ @foo[1]:v;    # (5 5)
```

Comment: yes - good answer